# Can't save CSV in Excel once imported into RStudio

Tags: csv

I'm using R 4.0.5 and RStudio 1.4.1106. Whenever I import a CSV into RStudio, I have to close it completely to be able to edit it in Excel, save, open RStudio and then re-import.

Is there just some setting I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved when a series of packages were updated. I suspect it was when updating readr as I was using read_csv to import.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).